# Appending strings then storing them into a vector

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm confused on where my logic for my function is incorrect. The goal is to return a vector of type string (`vector<string>`) where the characters of two different strings are paired up based on their indexes. This process would continue until the end of each string. For instance, given the variables below:

```
string strOne = "shop";
string strTwo = "fast";
vector<string> vec;


// when the program runs, vec should return {"sf", "ha", "os", "pt"}
// the first index of each string is paired together (e.g., "s" for strOne and "f" for strTwo) and added onto the *vec* variable
// the second index of each string is paired together (e.g., "h" for strOne and "a" for strTwo) and added onto the *vec* variable, etc
```

This is what I got so far:

```
vector<string> function1(string strOne, string strTwo, int i) 
{
    string result;
    vector<string> strVec;

    if (strOne.size() == 0 && strTwo.size() == 0) 
    {
        return strVec;
    } 

    if (i == 0) 
    {
        result = strOne.at(i) + strTwo.at(i);
        strVec.push_back(result);
        return strVec;
    } 
    else 
    {
        strVec = function1(strOne, strTwo, i- 1);
        result= strOne.at(i) + strTwo.at(i);
        strVec.push_back(result);
        return strVec;
    }
}


vector<string> function1(string strOne, string strTwo) {
    return function1(strOne, strTwo, strOne.size() - 1);
}
```

I created another function of the same name to be able to pass in more variables. From there, I created an if statement within that function to return an empty vector if both the strings are of size 0. For my case, I used the iterating int variable `i` to go into each string, then concatenate them into another string variable. I then added the string onto the declared vector variable. I would use recursion (required) to loop the process until it reaches the base case (the *i == 0* if statement). In the other function with less parameters, I call the other function that does the work.

Where is the fault in my logic?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding chars together does not behave how you are expecting. Let's say strOne[i] is A (65) and strTwo[i] is B (66). The result of `strOne[i] + strTwo[i]` is the character ƒ (131).
`result = strOne[i] + strTwo[i]` then converts this character into a one-character string. Instead try

```
result = strOne[i];
result += strTwo[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<string> function1(string strOne, string strTwo, int i) 
{
    // strOne and strTwo must have the same size

    string result=" ";//set result as an empty string because strings can be 
    //concatenated with '+' while characters cannot.
    vector<string> strVec;

    if (strOne.size() == 0 && strTwo.size() == 0) 
    {
        return strVec;
    } 

    if (i == 0) 
    {
        result = result+strOne.at(i) + strTwo.at(i);//strOne.at(i) and 
    //strTwo.at(i) are characters references.
        strVec.push_back(result);
        return strVec;
    } 
    else 
    {
        strVec = function1(strOne, strTwo, i- 1);
        result= result+strOne.at(i) + strTwo.at(i); 
        
        strVec.push_back(result);
        return strVec;
    }
}

vector<string> function1(string strOne, string strTwo)
{
    return function1(strOne, strTwo, strOne.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).